# Upgrading SASS in a way that I can downgrade if needed?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm using a very old version of SASS (3.1.15) in the Compass framework, and I want to upgrade to 3.4.3, which is the latest. I'm researching the process of upgrading, and after reading the SASS changelog, I'd like to be able to upgrade, then if I see a lot of errors and whatnot, revert back to the old version since I currently have actual development work to do in parallel with this research. I want to avoid being blocked due to legacy code being incompatible with new SASS, but I also want to see what issues an upgrade would bring, if any. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be as simple as this to upgrade:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall sass

$ sudo gem install sass --version 3.4.3
```

Then if you want to switch back to the old version:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall sass

$ sudo gem install sass --version 3.1.15
```

Answer (score 0):

Both [Bundler](http://bundler.io) and [RVM](http://rvm.io/) allow you to specify gems in their own way. Bundler is project-based, while RVM uses [gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics).